# JQuery Cycle plugin - Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, slideshow

I'm using JQuery cycle plugin to make a slideshow in HTML. I believe that I have done everything right but it's not in an actual slideshow frame, the pictures are just below eachother like this:
[image]

I'm asking for a fresh pair of eyes and brain to help fix this :)
Oh! Almost forgot, here's my code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-2.5.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/twitter_search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryEffects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/xml">
</script>
<div id="Slide#1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
// BeginOAWidget_Instance_2827522: #OAWidget
$(window).load(function() {


      $('#slider').flexslider({
        namespace: "flex-",             //{NEW} String: Prefix string attached to the class of every element generated by the plugin
    selector: ".slides > li",       //{NEW} Selector: Must match a simple pattern. '{container} > {slide}' -- Ignore pattern at your own peril
      animation: "slide",
       easing: "swing",               //{NEW} String: Determines the easing method used in jQuery transitions. jQuery easing plugin is supported!   
      direction: "horizontal",   //String: Select the sliding direction, 'horizontal' or 'vertical'
    reverse: false,                 //{NEW} Boolean: Reverse the animation direction
    animationLoop: false,             //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
    smoothHeight: true,            //{NEW} Boolean: Allow height of the slider to animate smoothly in horizontal mode   
      slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
      slideshowSpeed: 5000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
      animationSpeed: 600,         //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds  
      initDelay: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Set an initialization delay, in milliseconds
      randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order
       useCSS: true,                   //{NEW} Boolean: Slider will use CSS3 transitions if available
      touch: true,                    //{NEW} Boolean: Allow touch swipe navigation of the slider on touch-enabled devices
       video: false,                   //{NEW} Boolean: If using video in the slider, will prevent CSS3 3D Transforms to avoid graphical glitches
      directionNav: true,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)

      controlNav: true,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
      keyboard: true,              //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via keyboard left/right keys
      mousewheel: false,              //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via mousewheel
      prevText: "Previous",           //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
      nextText: "Next",               //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item
      pausePlay: false,               //Boolean: Create pause/play dynamic element
      pauseText: "Pause",             //String: Set the text for the "pause" pausePlay item
      playText: "Play",               //String: Set the text for the "play" pausePlay item
      startAt: 0,                //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
      pauseOnAction: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended.
      pauseOnHover: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering     
      start: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider loads the first slide
      controlsContainer: "",          //Selector: Declare which container the navigation elements should be appended too. Default container is the flexSlider element. Example use would be ".flexslider-container", "#container", etc. If the given element is                                                 not found, the default action will be taken.
       manualControls: "",             //Selector: Declare custom control navigation. Example would be ".flex-control-nav li" or "#tabs-nav li img", etc. The number of elements in your controlNav should match the number of slides/tabs.
       // Carousel Options
    itemWidth: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Box-model width of individual carousel items, including horizontal borders and padding.
    itemMargin: 10,                  //{NEW} Integer: Margin between carousel items.
    minItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Minimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when below this.
    maxItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Maxmimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when above this limit.
    move: 0,                        //{NEW} Integer: Number of carousel items that should move on animation. If 0, slider will move all visible items.
      before: function(){},           //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
      after: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
      end: function(){}               //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider reaches the last slide (asynchronous)
      });
      });
// EndOAWidget_Instance_2827522
  </script>
  <div id="main-container">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="main" class="wrapper clearfix">
      <!-- FlexSlider -->
      <div id="container">
        <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li> <img src="images/1.png" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/2.png" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/3.png" /> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel" class="flexslider" style="display:none;">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li> <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" /> </li>
            <li> <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" /> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #main -->
  </div>
  <!-- #main-container -->
</div>
```

If for some reason this isn't displaying correctly, here's a pastebin :)
http://pastebin.com/Zq5Xww6k

Thanks in advance,
CMNatic

Comment: You are using cycle, but you are showing us the js for the flexslider....? And you have 3 instances of jQuery "jquery-1.6.min.js" and "jquery-1.7.2.min.js" and "jquery.js".... (and modernizr should be loaded before the jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with this plugin but from the effects, it looks like the html and javasrcipt are not enough, looks like you are missing css,

for example here are the basics

    `.slides {

        position: relative;

        height: 200px; /*height required*/

        width: 500px /* width required*/

    }

    .slides li {

        position: absolute;

        top: 0; left: 0;

    }`